# Perl: Sorting 2D array with multiple columns based on a particular column

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

Pseudo code:

```
my @unsortedArray = { ["Harry", 10], ["Tim", 8], ["Joe", 3]};
my @sortedArray = ?????
```

Final sortedArray should be sorted based on col-2 (integers), taking care of the 1-to-1 relationship with the "Name of the person" (col-1). Final result should look like:

```
sortedArray should be { ["Joe", 3], ["Tim", 8], ["Harry", 10] };
```

Comment: `@array = { ... }` is (almost always) incorrect syntax. Use `@array = ( ... )` to assign to an array.

Comment: @mob : I wonder what edge case you had in mind when you mentioned *almost* :)

Comment: @Zaid: `@array_containing_a_single_hashref = { ... }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give a predicate to `sort`, that is: a function which is evaluated to compare elements of the list.

```
my @unsorted = ( ["Harry", 10], ["Tim", 8], ["Joe", 3] );

my @sorted = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @unsorted;
```

In the predicate (the expression in curly braces), `$a` and `$b` are the elements of the outer list which are compared.

`sort` is only concerned with one-dimensional lists, so it won't mess with the internal structure of the elements of the outer list. So the relationship between name and number is retained effortlessly.

Refer to `perldoc -f sort` and `perldoc perlop` for more details.

Comment: my @sorted = sort { $a->[1] > $b->[1] } @unsorted;
easier to understand

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was using just "sort", which is sorting just the second column.

Comment: @Mike no that's wrong - the predicate of vanilla `sort` is more like `{ "$a" cmp "$b" }`, so you'd be comparing something like `"ARRAY(0x2229d48)"` with `"ARRAY(0x2229d98)"`. Any resemblance to sorting on the second column is coincidental.

Comment: @askovpen - This does nothing if `$a` is less than `$b`, and there's no guarantee that `$a` is earlier in the array than `$b`. The [<=>](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) and it's text based cousin `cmp`) is a special operator just for the `sort` function. Try sorting `qw(2 5 28 3 1 62 4 81)`. I get `1, 2, 5, 3, 28, 62, 4, 81` doing it your way.

Comment: Agree with David W. askovpen's comment is wrong and harder to understand

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient solution, especially for larger arrays, may be to use `List::UtilsBy::nsort_by`:

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( nsort_by );

my @unsorted = ( ["Harry", 10], ["Tim", 8], ["Joe", 3] );

my @sorted = nsort_by { $_->[1] } @unsorted;
```

While in small cases the overhead is not likely to be noticed, for more complex functions the `O(n log n)` key extraction cost becomes higher, and it is more preferrable to extract the "sort key" of each value only once, which is what `nsort_by` does.